# MySQL - Select row if field has value, otherwise select with null value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create query with user_id parameter that would select one row per article_id where row with set user_id has priority. For example:

If user_id = 1, rows with id 2, 3, 4 should be selected.

If user_id = 2, rows with id 1, 3, 5 should be selected.

If user_id = 17, rows with id 1, 3, 4 should be selected.

Please consider pair (user_id, article_id) unique.

```
id   user_id   article_id
1    null      8
2    1         8
3    null      9
4    null      10
5    2         10
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add expected output

Comment: Hey @MadhurBhaiya, I did it when created Question, there are 3 different examples with expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a1
WHERE user_id = 1 OR
    user_id IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM articles a2 WHERE a2.article_id = a1.article_id AND a2.user_id = 1)
ORDER BY user_id IS NULL
```

This will find all the articles which match `user_id` = 1, or a `NULL` `user_id` where there was not a matching entry with the requested `user_id`. The results are ordered by `user_id IS NULL` which will be 0 for an article which matches the `user_id`, and 1 for an article where `user_id` is NULL, thus prioritising the actual matches on `user_id`.

Output (for `user_id=1`):

```
id  user_id     article_id
2   1           8
3   (null)      9
4   (null)      10
```

Output (for `user_id=2`):

```
id  user_id     article_id
5   2           10
1   (null)      8
3   (null)      9
```

Output (for `user_id=17`):

```
id  user_id     article_id
1   (null)      8
3   (null)      9
4   (null)      10
```